# How do I change the picture on my profile?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In Counter Strike: Global Offensive how do I change the picture that comes up when I kill/get killed?

Answer (score 6):

CS:GO is linked to your Steam account. Any changes made to the steam account, including the profile picture will change your account in CS:GO.